# Changing terminal transparency with a command in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I change the transparency of the Terminal windows in Ubuntu with a command line?

I already know about the profile method but want a command so that I can quickly swap between transparent and opaque.

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Is this really off topic? I use terminal for building and running and the command I'm looking is like an API request :)

Comment: @sarnold: GNOME Terminal 2.30.2

Comment: I discovered the Unix stackexchange and cross-posted. Got a response that works :) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/changing-gnome-terminal-transparency-with-a-command-in-ubuntu/24618#24618

Answer (score 2):

According to the manpage for `gnome-terminal`, what you want to do does not appear to be directly achievable.

```
NAME
   gnome-terminal — is a terminal emulation application.

SYNOPSIS
   gnome-terminal  [-e,  --command=STRING]   [-x, --execute ]  [--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME]  [--tab-with-profile=PRO‐
   FILENAME]    [--window-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--tab-with-profile-internal-id=PROFILEID]    [--role=ROLE]
   [--show-menubar]   [--hide-menubar]   [--geometry=GEOMETRY]   [--disable-factory]  [-t, --title=TITLE]  [--working-direc‐
   tory=DIRNAME]  [--usage]  [-?, --help]
```

However, you might be able to achieve something similar to your goal via creating a couple of different profiles and then using either the `--window-with-profile` or `--tab-with-profile` options.  Combined with aliases in your `.*rc` file, and you could be good to go.

Comment: Is there a command to close the current terminal window? Those commands open a new instance of terminal

Comment: `exit` should close your current term window...

Comment: Note that the `gnome-terminal(1)` manpage was written by someone else because the GNOME team doesn't "do" documentation. The manpage just vaguely says something like "supports all VT102 and VT220 escape codes", but I fully expect it doesn't support _all_ those codes and I fully expect they introduced _new_ codes, too -- one of which _might_ swap transparency on the fly. But just maybe. (The GNOME team is also known for removing configurable options whenever they think they can.)

Comment: In the cross-posted question there [is an answer showing how to swap opacity / transparency](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/changing-gnome-terminal-transparency-with-a-command-in-ubuntu/24618#24618) -- showing that once again you cannot count on the _lack_ of documentation to mean something is or isn't possible with the GNOME software.

Comment: What a giant ball of fail.  *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains an answer for this question that I got from the unix board :)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/changing-gnome-terminal-transparency-with-a-command-in-ubuntu/24618#24618